# Send message from page 1 to page 2 using content script + background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to write a chrome extension to send some data from site 1 to site 2. I have created two content scripts (for each of sites) and a background script. Following are the scripts and explanation of what I am doing with the error I am getting.

**Manifest File:**

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Testing",
  "homepage_url": "https://www.test.co.uk",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "src/bg/background.js" ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "page action demo",
    "default_popup": "src/page_action/page_action.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://www.site1.co.uk/*",
    "*://site1.co.uk/*",
    "*://www.site2.co.uk/*",
    "*://site2.co.uk/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.site1.co.uk/*",
        "*://site1.co.uk/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject-pg1.js"
      ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.site2.co.uk/*",
        "*://site2.co.uk/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject-pg2.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Background script**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (request.data) {
      console.log(request.data);

      if (request.data == "pg1") {
          chrome.tabs.query({ active: true },
              function (tabs) {
                  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { data: "from page 1" }, function (response) { });
              });
      }

      if (request.data == "pg2") {
          chrome.tabs.query({ active: true },
              function (tabs) {
                  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { data: "frome page 2" }, function (response) { });
              });
      }
  }

  chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
  sendResponse();
});
```

**Page 1 inject-pg1.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: 'pg1'
});


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {    
      if (request.data) {
          if (request.data == "pg2") {
              console.log("from page 2")
          }
      }
  });
```

**Page 2 inject-pg2.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: 'pg2'
});


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {    
      if (request.data) {
          if (request.data == "pg1") {
              console.log("from page 1")
          }
      }
  });
```

There are 2 websites for this, each having their own content script. When page 1 is loaded, it sends a message to background script which sends a message to page 2 depending on condition if message is received from page 1 or vice verse.

But on the page 2 the message is not received, is this because it is in another tab? I also sometimes get an error in background.js `Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` in `tabs[0].id`

Is this a correct way to implement this, or is this even possible? If there is a better solution, please point me to the right direction. Thankyou

Comment: Currently your background script gets a list of active tabs in all windows that may have unrelated sites loaded, and sends `"from page 1"` even though your content script expects `"pg1"`. Do you want the first opened of the two sites to provide data for the other one opened later? In this case you can do even without a background page: simply use `chrome.storage` in the content scripts to write and read data.

Comment: First of all, thanks for pointing the issue where content script is expecting `pg1` and bg script is sending something else. Yes I will try `chrome.storage` and see how it goes.